# emailing a string gathered using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, string, post

I am trying to email a string that was collected from a web page via php, however I am not having any luck. Lots of info on making jQuery forms but can't find any that are simply emailing a string.

here is what I have so far:

```
 $('.questionFive').click(function(){
    $.post("mail.php", preSubmit()) 
 });

// this works well, and returns the string as desired.
function preSubmit(){
    var optionTexts = [];
    $("section").each(function(){
        var h2 = $(this).find("h2").text();
        optionTexts.push(h2);
        $("ol li", this).each(function() { optionTexts.push($(this).text()) });
        optionTexts.push("\n");
    });
    var optionString = optionTexts.toString();
    var splitText = optionString.split(",");
    alert(splitText);
    return splitText;
}

// mail.php file
<?php
if (isset($_POST['mailstring']) {
    $mail = $_POST['mailstring'];
    mail('me@email.com', 'My Subject', $mail);
}
?>
```

Comment: have you verified the form works standalone from the jQuery - i would first eliminate that possibility.  submit the form manually with your mail.php file - this can tell us both that the server is configured properly for email and everything lines up with your html and php submission script.  also can we please see the html? ty

Comment: also worth noting you are missing a few semicolons on couple lines that will be causing issues. specifically the line with your alert in the preSubmit function:      alert(splitText)  and your optionText array push calls

Comment: semicolons in JavaScript are a very good idea, but they're not required.

Comment: fix the semicolon, that wasn't issue I don't think. The string returns fine, it's actually sending the string to php that is the issue I think? I can see the alert pop up in a way I would like it sent.

Comment: http://hellowoo.com/apps/VHSurvey here is the full html if you need that

Comment: @orzechowskid  Thats not fully true. In most cases where you have a newline you do not require a semicolon. But there are situations where you can't leave it out `test(); [NL] (function() {})()` where you can't omit it.

Comment: @t.niese very true - I wasn't specific enough.

Comment: I have confirmed a normal form send works fine. its this combination that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You're sending a single string as your POST data, but your PHP script is expecting a key/value pair.  If you look at the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for `$.post()`, you'll see that you have to pass an object as the `data` parameter:

```
$.post("mail.php", {
    foo: "bar",
    abc: true
});
```

Comment: ah, I see now. thank you. Didn't realize I have to return an object.

Answer (score 0):

Change the return on the preSubmit function to

```
return {"mailstring":splitText};
```